# RoutePrefix Not Found in WebApi 2,2

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, routes

I have build a Web API 2.2 project using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition. Attribute `RoutePrefix` is not found. After searching the internet, I found PM Console Command : `Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core -reinstall`. It solved the problem but as soon as I right click on the Solution and Click `Rebuild Solution`. Attribute `RoutePrefix` again starts giving error of not found. Can anybody tell me what is wrong with Visual Studio.

Comment: What is the actual error you are getting on console?

Comment: @HameedSyed No error on console, Just RoutePrefix and related functions become not found.

Comment: Just have a look @ this article,might help http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.in/2016/08/creating-web-api-project.html and also can you post the code of your webapiconfig  class file and also application_start.

Answer (score 0):

Add a RoutePrefix attribute to the controller. This attribute defines the initial URI segments for all methods on the controller.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Employee")]
public class EmployeeController : ApiController
{
    // ...
}
```